# Getting each element of a list and mapping it to a struct in elixir

Tags: elixir

How would you take a list of strings, eg.

```
["jeff", "bezos", "21"]
```

and map that to a struct

```
%{:fistname => "jeff", :lastname => "bezos", :age => "21"}
```

Is it possible to use the Enum functions or would you use the map functions. I need this struct in the specified format so that I can then send it to a database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume the strings are in the same order every time?

Then you can just pattern match:

```
[firstname, lastname, age] = array
%{:fistname => firstname, :lastname => lastname, :age => age}
```

If the list contains more than 3 elements:

```
[firstname, lastname, age | _] = array
%{:fistname => firstname, :lastname => lastname, :age => age}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. So all the data comnes from a csv file, but I only need the first 5 for one struct and then the rest go into another struct would this work say if I did option 2, took the first 3 then did a similar thing but took the 7 after the first 3? or would it have to be done another way?

Comment: maybe something like {_,_,_, other_fields...} = array

Comment: well you can do `[firstname, lastname, age | rest] = array`

Comment: all the additional fields will be in `rest` which is also a list

Comment: O right and then you call rest and do the same thing again??

Answer (score 4):

You can zip the list of keys with your list of values and then pass that to `Map.new/1`:

```
iex(1)> Enum.zip([:firstname, :lastname, :age], ["jeff", "bezos", "21"]) |> Map.new
%{age: "21", firstname: "jeff", lastname: "bezos"}
```